How do I print formated text in a barchart segment using sgrender/sgplot?
I´d like to make a barchart in SAS using proc sgplot/sgrender and be able to adjust the font color according to the fill color or the particular segment value. The fill color could go from dark to light as the font at some value the font color switches from white to black to get a good contrast.
This is possible with proc gchart using a annotate dataset and the subgroup option which makes it to target a specific segment. This seems difficult when working categorical variables and graphs made with proc sgplot/sgrender.
The first example I´d like to implement in the other two having font color switching depending if the segment type is a SUV. 
[enter image description here][1]
proc sql;
   create table cars as
    select make, type, count(*) as count 
        from sashelp.cars 
     group by make, type
     order by make, type;
quit;

data anno_text;
    set cars;
    length function color $8;
    xsys='2'; ysys='2'; 
    when='a';
    midpoint=make;
    position='e';
    subgroup=type;
    function='label';
    text=trim(left(count));
    if type='SUV' then color='black';
    else color='white';
run;


proc gchart data=cars(where=(make < 'D')) anno=work.anno_text; 
   vbar make / type=sum sumvar=count outside=sum inside=sum subgroup=Type;
run;

proc sgplot data=cars(where=(make < 'D')) sganno=work.anno_text;
     vbar  make / group=Type groupdisplay=stack  freq=count seglabel datalabel;
run;


proc template;
  define statgraph barchart;
    begingraph / attrpriority=none  ;

 
      layout lattice;
            barchart category=make  response=count
             /group=type groupdisplay=stack segmentlabel=true barlabel=true
          ;
        discretelegend "carmodels";
      endlayout;
    endgraph;
  end;
run;

proc sgrender data=cars(where=(make < 'D')) template=barchart sganno=work.anno_text;
run;

![1 Gchart and switching font color]: https://i.sstatic.net/5VKS1hHO.png

Show a simple example.  Use either a SASHELP dataset or a simple dataset you provide.  Show how you did it with GCHART.  Show what you tried with statistical graphics procedures.
